# How to handle thin geometry for the purposes of voxelization in a 3D texture?

Tags: opengl, shader, voxel

I am currently trying to make a shader that takes some arbitrary geometry and creates a voxelized approximation of said geometry.

My current way of handling it is that, if I look straight down from above, I render the geometry layer by layer, discarding all geometry not contained in the current layer. Which creates something like this:

[image]

The issue whith this is, if I have a perfectly vertical thin part of an object (like a wall) this geometry will result in an infinetely thin triangle when seen from above, and thus the corresponding fragment is not actually visible.

I nevertheless need to capture this kind of geometry. Even if something is infinetly thin it should still fully occupy the voxel it is contained on.

So the net effect would do something like:

[image]

Can I do this at any point in the rendering pipeline like the tesellation shader or geometry shader?

Comment: Since this is now (at least) the third question about scene voxelization and it's problems: Have you read the article about that in [OpenGL Inside](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-SparseVoxelization.pdf). The first part should give you an idea on how to do it and can easily be adapted to work with a 3D texture.

Comment: There is something called as conservative rasterization that might help you with thin geometry. Have look here https://developer.nvidia.com/content/dont-be-conservative-conservative-rasterization

In simple words it tries to find bounds of your pritive and try to enlarge it so it covers pixel.